# Set default attribute value for existing addresses

Tags: magento2, customer-address, default-values

Is there a way to create a new custom address attribute and set the default option to all existing addresses? Right now it only shows the default value when creating a new address and all existing addresses have this new attribute as null.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times the answer is pretty simple: update the values in the database with a simple query.

If you want to do the "magento way" create a console command and load the address collection and update the values via a simple script.